# IIS displays blank page

Tags: .net, windows, iis

We are hosting .NET applications on Windows Server 2019. We have a problem with displaying pages that have the word "win" in the link (`www.mydomain.com/win`, `/win_blabla`, `/blawinbla`, etc).

The problem is only appears on one server, it is updated with latest updates and patches.

No errors are found in the event log.

Server update, iis, firewall check

Comment: Enable FRT to check further. If this machine was hacked like https://serverfault.com/questions/1130899/iis-returning-empty-body-with-200-response-for-certain-urls you should hire a security professional to help.